# sequence padding in keras

Tags: python, types, keras

I'm trying to build a recommendation system using medical drugs reviews, I elaborated a script (link : [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hhhNfjkzD0e9Fo7_nrYTOVwT2xYyJfbM][1]  that enable me to import data and do the pre-processing.
Now I working on the training model, but through a few lines I have noticed that there is a problem with the imported data, here is my code :

```
from f import Load_TrainData
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

x_med, rating, cond,vocabulary,vocabulary_inv=Load_TrainData()
sequence_len_med=1000
vocabulary_size_med=len(vocabulary_inv)
input_shape_med=(sequence_len_med,)
model_input_med=Input(shape=input_shape_med)
x_train1=sequence.pad_sequences(x_med,maxlen=sequence_len_med)
```

the problem is with the last line !
here is the error :

```
ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: 0
```

I think that the problem is with the data type, but I did'nt know how to fix it !
here is a link to my dataset :
   [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YUqzo7mrpnSWSESmCfsOB1tdmO-qBnAO][2]

here is a sample for the data I'm using (x_med):
[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQzBb.png][1]

Comment: show a sample of `x_med`

Comment: @SreeramTP here is a link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EGrnPueS41qy1ZoEguday-GTtgsAnGE0

Comment: Providing a GDrive link is not a good idea because many of us can't acess drive services at work. So it is better to give a sample pasted along with the question or a github link

Comment: @SreeramTP I have edited the post so you can check it

Answer (score 0):

First column seems to be a string (containing an integer and a med name), not an integer as required :
https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/

Comment: Does that mean that the column I use must contain integers after all the pre-processing steps ?